# php mongo client get yesterday recrods

Tags: php, mongodb

Could someone please let me know how to get yesterday records in Mongo DB using PHP Mongo client class.

Here is what I have tried but the result is 0(there are already records in yesterday date), I think I'm doing wrong.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"));
$fromDate = $date." 00:00:00";
$toDate   = $date." 23:59:59";

$filters  = array(
                'orderDate'=>array(
                            '$lt'=>$fromDate,
                            '$gte'=>$toDate,
                       )
               );
$records  = $transCollec->find($filters);
echo $records->count(); //0
```

### Update

I'm saving order date this way in mongo:

```
//This date is comming from third party
$transactionDate = new Zend_Date($transactionApi["Stat"]["datetime"], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'en');
//this will save into mongodb
$transaction['orderDate'] = $transactionDate->toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
orderDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: You are doing it in error and looking at only the time between the "last minute of the day". What you want to instead ask is `'$gte' => startOfToday, '$lt' => startOfTomorrow` and forget trying to notate the last minute of the day completely. The "less than" already takes care as that as does the "equal to" part of "greater than or equal to". And of course it's likely these are actually `Date` objects in BSON. So use the real dates and not "strings".

Comment: Really helpful comment.

Comment: It's also "really helpful" to even keep using that same "meaningful" declaration of varible names in your own usage. because `startOfTomorrow` means exactly what it sounds like. I did also warn you about using "strings". Don't store strings in a database. And for the next helpful thing. You already asked your question. Someone answered and told you your mistake. When you have **new questions** you [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and you do not "change your existing question". Once someone answers, all "edits" are off. You get what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the posted question, the thing that immediately is noticeable is, you are trying to find records of previous day, but your condition is not matching, values of `$lt` and `$gte` need to be swapped, like:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"));
$fromDate = $date." 00:00:00";
$toDate   = $date." 23:59:59";

$filters  = array(
    'orderDate'=> array(
        '$lt' => $toDate, //changed
        '$gte' => $fromDate, //changed
    )
);
$records  = $transCollec->find($filters);
echo $records->count();
```

Comment: I think there's a few more problems than just that. Also unlikely the field is actually a "string" as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, but there's not much of info provided in the question.